Direction of the friction force exerted on a cart
Here's a picture of my question:



In this picture, the vehicle is accelerating to the right due to the horse's pull, and opposite arrows are used to denote action-reaction pairs described in Newton's third law of motion. Now, I'd like to determine the direction of the friction force exerted on the wheels by the ground. The answer says that $F_6$ is the friction force exerted on the wheels, but I feel that the correct answer should be $F_5$ because the friction force on an object is, to my knowledge of physics, exerted in such a way that prevents the object from moving relative to the surface. Did I get anything wrong? Thank you.


the friction force on an object is, to my knowledge of physics, exerted in such a way that prevents the object from moving relative to the surface.

That's correct. Notice that the wheel isn't sliding on the ground. The friction force on a rolling wheel is static, not kinetic.
The rolling wheel can't be treated as a point. It's better to plot forces as this:

The wheel contacts with ground at point A. $F_5$ wants to drag the wheel to the right. The wheel isn't sliding at point A, so the friction force $F_6$ acts on the opposite direction.
The wheel should be regarded as a lever with its center's distance to the ground fixed. $F_6$ provides a torque of $F_6R$ to rotate the wheel.

Hi, I've edited my post. Will it change the answer? Thank you.

@Boar The answer remains the same.
